# PySide6/QT onefile app bundled with Pyinstaller takes a long time to launch MacOS .app

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller, pyside6

The following code:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication,QSystemTrayIcon,QMenu)
from PySide6.QtGui import QAction

app = QApplication([])
app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)

#Create Tray
tray = QSystemTrayIcon()
tray.setVisible(True)

# Create the menu
menu = QMenu()

# Add a Quit option to the menu.
actionQuit = QAction("Quit")
actionQuit.triggered.connect(app.quit)
menu.addAction(actionQuit)

# Add the menu to the tray
tray.setContextMenu(menu)

app.exec()
```

The Following Pyinstaller command:

```
pyinstaller --windowed --onefile './Dev-Menu-Test.py'
```

The dock icon will launch. Then disappear briefly only to return after about 8-10 seconds. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Instead of creating a single file, you should opt for one directory i.e. multiple files, because single file is large in size, and it needs to be unpacked every time trying to execute it, and that's why the execution takes time to start.

Comment: That seems to have resolved it. I would take that as an answer! Thank you.

Comment: Great! No problem.